# How can I disable testing for a Haskell package in Nix?

Tags: haskell, nix

I'm trying to get a development environment going for Haskell, using Nix. I have a default.nix that just refers to my .cabal file for the list of packages. But one package I want to use, numhask-space, won't build, because the tests are failing. So I'm trying to override it and skip the tests.

Here's my default.nix:

```
# default.nix
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> { };
in
  pkgs.haskellPackages.developPackage {
    root = ./.;
    modifier = drv:
      pkgs.haskell.lib.addBuildTools drv (with pkgs.haskellPackages;
        [ cabal-install
          ghcid
        ]);
    source-overrides = {
      numhask-space = pkgs.haskell.lib.dontCheck pkgs.haskellPackages.numhask-space;
        };
  }
```

But I must not be doing this right, because I get the error:

`cabal2nix: user error (Failed to fetch source. Does this source exist? Source {sourceUrl = "/nix/store/w3pcvlj7b0k44v629k00kw2b0k86fcyj-numhask-space-0.3.0", sourceRevision = "", sourceHash = Guess "", sourceCabalDir = ""})`

In short, how can I override this haskell package so that it doesn't run the tests, and I can install it in my development environment?

Comment: Did you try `overrides = self: super: { numhask-space = dontCheck super.numhask-space; }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`source-overrides` overrides sources of the packages, that is, literally, the `src` attributes, rather than packages as a whole. You should use the `overrides` argument instead:

```hs
    overrides = self: super: {
      numhask-space = pkgs.haskell.lib.dontCheck super.numhask-space;
    };
```